# Passing function as an argument of another function in PHP

Tags: php, function, oop

I want to pass function (not the result) as an argument of another function. Let's say I have

```
function double_fn($fn)
```

and i want to run given function ($fn) two times. Is there such mechanism in PHP? I know you in python function is a kind of variable but is PHP similar?

@edit
is there similar way to use methods?

```
function double_fn(parrot::sing())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 5.3 *(note)* you do this with closures quite naturally:

```
function double_fn(callable $fn)
{
    $fn();
    $fn();
}

double_fn(function() {
    echo "hi";
});
```

*(note) type hint only since 5.4*

The [callable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) type can be a few things:

1. a string comprising the function name to call,
2. a closure (as above)
3. an array comprising class (or instance) and method to call

Examples of the above is explained in the manual.

#### Update

> edit is there similar way to use methods?
>
> `function double_fn(parrot::sing())`

Doing that will pass the *result* of `parrot::sing()` into the function; to pass a "reference" to the static method you would need to use either:

```
double_fn('parrot::sing');
double_fn(['parrot', 'sing']);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's... a bit different. Pass the function name as a string.

```
function foo()
{
  echo "foobar\n";
}

function double_fn($fn)
{
  $fn();
  $fn();
}

double_fn('foo');
```

Comment: Did you hide under a rock since 5.3? :)

Comment: @Jack: Why would I want to define an anonymous function that just calls another function?

Comment: Who said anything about anonymous functions calling another function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) introduced in PHP 5.3.0:

```
function double_fn($fn) {
  $fn();
}


double_fn(function(){
  // fonction body
});
```

or:

```
$myFn = function(){
  // fonction body
};

double_fn($myFn);
```